# Performance of a request on XML file

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml

I have an SQL-Server database from which I need to extract information that is stored in a XML file (inside the db).

I have the table : mc_report

that contain an nvarchar field called : original_xml

I want to do something like

```
select id from mc_report where original_xml like '%mytext%';
```

Knowing that the table could potentially contains hundreds (or even thousands) of records, and that each XML file is hundreds of lines long

The xml files look likes that : http://pastebin.com/WQyvzngG

I want to filter by serial

line 242 in the pastebin

```
<entry name="serial" type="string">Z4MDPDAVT</entry>
```

Is it going to be fast ? Or is it going to take forever ?

If not fast, what are the other options that I have ?

Comment: What about *just try it* ? Is the XML stored in data type `XML` or is it stored as kind of string? If you show your XML's structure one migth help you...

Comment: The problem is, right now the database only contains 10 records, I need to implement a code to run in production that need to work when the db gets bigger

Comment: You can be 100% sure, that a `LIKE` with a leading `%` will perform absolutely bad in big data...

Comment: @Shnugo : Yes, that's what I suspected

Comment: Show your XML and what/how you want to filter and answer the question about data type of storage column...

Comment: I added the information in the question description

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might put this into a WHERE clause:

```
WHERE YourXmlColumn.exist('//entry[@name="serial" and .="Z4MDPDAVT"]')=1
```

If you know the higher node (like *Looking into "sound_card" ...*) you might reduce the time drastically as XQuery doesnt have to travers through every single entry until it finds a fitting.

If you want to put your search criteria dynamically you can either use

```
DECLARE @prm AS VARCHAR(100)='Z4MDPDAVT';
[...]
WHERE YourXmlColumn.exist('//entry[@name="serial" and .=sql:variable("@prm")]')=1
```

or you can use the content of a column of the running query like

```
WHERE YourXmlColumn.exist('//entry[@name="serial" and .=sql:column("ColumnName")]')=1
```

If you really get into performance troubles you might think about a trigger to write the values you are searching after into indexed columns.

You might think about an XML index too, but I would try to avoid this...

Comment: I just found, that this is stored as a `NVARCHAR`... If you are allowed to change this, then change it to "real" XML. If not, my code will not work unless you change the `YourXmlColumn` to `CAST(YourXmlColumn AS XML)`

Comment: Thank you, I didn't know that exists.

Comment: @BlueMagma Yeah, SQL-Server and XML are quite a powerfull couple, but you cannot expect miracles... If this solves your issue, please click the upvote and the acceptance check thx!

Answer (score 0):

> select id from mc_report where original_xml like '%mytext%';

LIKE %SOMTHING is a performance issue, XML or not. It is THE performance issue (outside of "what is an index") that beginner people do. It simply will not scale - which is why there is full text search in SQL Server for some time now.

> The problem is, right now the database only contains 10 records, I need to 
>   implement a code to run in production that need to work when the db gets bigge

So develop on a larger database. Issue 2 of beginner developers: Not using proper data sizes. Get a generator and generate fake data. Then you KNOW how it behaves.

Comment: I would be really happy to have a bigger database, unfortunately, I can't fill it up myself, the database belong to a tool provided by another company, I need to read it to detect when the tool has finished (which happen when the database contain the XML). If I were to run the tool again and again to fill the db, it would take forever, the tool take 14h to finish. Only production can fill the db.

Comment: No, that is not true. A SQL database can be filled with random data easily.  Good enough for performance trials. Without testing performance you do not do your job.

Comment: Why do you have to be so aggressive ? You're really not helpful. I don't want to test for something I already know : this will be slow, I know, I'm not stupid. Try constructive answer like Shnugo instead of criticizing. You don't know anything about the context in which I am working.